# Setting UITableViewCell selected background color with UIAppearence not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiappearance

I want to change the selected color of all my `UITableViewCell`s. I am already using `UIAppearence` to define basic properties for some other UI elements and it works.

However, setting

```
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764706, green: 0.9411764706, blue: 0.9411764706, alpha: 1)
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

Results in a strange glitch, the cell losing the selection color, although the `UITableViewCell`s is still selected:

[image: UITableViewCell disappearing selection]

The glitch is not caused by UI code because setting the selected color directly in `UITableViewCell.awakeFromNib` works fine, the selected cell stays the desired color.

**Edit**: This happens with all the different cells. The cells do not do anything interesting, just set stuff like label colors, etc in `awakeFromNib` and some `RxSwift` binding in a model setter to set the values of the various labels. The VCs just react to the cell getting selected by calling a delegate method (using `modelSelected` from `RxSwift`).

**Edit**: The VC with the `UITableView` is the "left side" of a `UISplitViewController`. The "right side" is a `UINavigationController` and navigation in this `UINavigationController` using `setViewControllers` after tapping the cell causes the strange glitch.

Comment: So what you want is that when you tap once on the cell, the highlight will stay there? Or is it if you tap on a cell, the highlight should animate for a more milliseconds? I don't get much your "strange glitch" problem.

Comment: You must set it before cell init, so try to set it in your app delegate

Comment: @Glenn by glitch I mean the cell getting deselected

Comment: Is it a grouped or plain tableView?

Comment: @CatalinaT. plain

Comment: Where is the code being run? the one which calls the `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView`.

Comment: @CatalinaT. in a helper class method called from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: @IgorKulman Could you please post your code of your tableViewCell? And perhaps some delegate methods, such as didSelect.

Comment: @Glenn edited. I do not think it is related to the actual cells, because as I set, setting the color in `awakeFromNib`instead of using `UIAppearence` works fine

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

So after some investigations I was able to reproduce your "glitch" :) I downloaded RxSwift and then tried their tableView sample. I use RxSwift too but I don't use their tableView delegate/datasource extensions. I also made a custom tableViewCell.

After overriding the `setSelected` method of the `UITableViewCell`, and not calling its super method, the same case happened. Actually, even without using RxSwift, this should happen.

So again, make sure in your tableView class, if you do not need to do anything with `setSelected`, don't override it. Otherwise, when overriding super class methods, make sure you're calling the super.method(), just like what you're doing in your controller's `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Actually, I do not override `setSelected`in any of my cells

Comment: Hmmm, in that case, you might wanna share some pieces of your codes in your cell, and how you implement the tableView delegate RxSwift extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It should work perfectly fine, I have tried in an iOS application.

Try using a different color for the selected background, It might be same as you cell's background color

And verify that UITableViewCell#selection property is not set to none

[image]

Comment: Why would I set selection to none when the whole point is keeping the selected cell look selected.

Comment: try generating a new app to test the same, it will work perfectly fine.
there must be something in your code that effects the same.